# Windows 10 boot option in Grub Menu failed to boot windows 10 (21H1)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi

Windows 10 version 21H1 upgrade destroyed my grub menu on both of my Desktop and Notebook. I fixed the grub menu and face new issue.

### Windows 10 boot option in Grub Menu failed to boot windows 10 (21H1)

I finally found the easy fix for my problems so I post it here just in case it can help others.

I have done these steps:

1. That Windows is installed and configured to boot via UEFI.
2. Ubuntu is installed and configured to boot via UEFI.
3. Grub Menu at boot and dual boots worked perfectly.
4. After Windows has been upgrade to version 21H1.
   Grub Menu disappeared and computer now boot straight to windows 10 only.
5. ### I use UBUNTU installation USB booted up AND Install Boot-repair

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair

```
  and chosen "Recommended Repair"
  and successfully install grub menu again.
```

6. Windows 10 boot option, started booting but fail to auto-repair the booting and keep failing even try a few times.
7. I tried Boot-Repair again but still windows 10 failed to auto-repair booting.

Answer (score -3):

### Solution that worked for me finally.

### (with out using any command line or other programs)

1. I used

https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

sudo apt install grub-customizer

Once installed, launch the software from your application launcher
to load up in UBUNTU 20.04
and just click SAVE after it finished loaded.
(I did not change any things)

2. reboot
3. select windows boot in the grub menu.
4. Allow windows 10 to auto-repair booting by itself.
5. It finished with success repaired displayed.
6. Reboot.

My Windows 10 now booted normally.

Comment: This is absurd and using Boot Repair as well. What you describe is totally expected with any Windows feature update - for your convenience Windows changes the boot order to itself to allow the multiple reboots needed for the update installation - and all you had to do is open UEFI settings > Boot, change it back to Ubuntu, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` to re-add a proper Windows entry. That's absolutely all, no 3rd party software needed.

Comment: And grub only boots working Windows. Windows often with major updates changes settings like fast start up back on, so you have to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu to then get into Windows repairs and redo any settings changes in Windows. Windows with major updates may also update UEFI settings to defaults like Intel RST from your change to AHCI to boot Ubuntu. Then you have to go back and redo those settings.